# Dropdown select , update user account activate/deactivate

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I'm new in php how can I make this work

delete.php

```
<?php
include_once 'dbconfig.php';
if($_POST['del_id'])
{
    $id = $_POST['del_id']; 
    $stmt=$db_con->prepare("UPDATE tbluser set status=1 WHERE id=:id");
    $stmt->execute(array(':id'=>$id));   
}
?>
```

I want to add an active/inactive dropdown choice in my edit form page but I dont know how to make it work I dont know how to call the delete.php so that when i choose inactive and submit the form it will not show on my datatable

edit_form.php

```
<?php
include_once 'dbconfig.php';

if($_GET['edit_id'])
{
    $id = $_GET['edit_id']; 
    $stmt=$db_con->prepare("SELECT * FROM tbluser WHERE id=:id");
    $stmt->execute(array(':id'=>$id));  
    $row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}
?>
<div id="dis">
</div>
<form method='post' id='emp-UpdateForm' action='#'>  
<table class='table table-bordered'>
    <input type='hidden' name='id' value='<?php echo $row['id']; ?>' />
    <tr>
        <td>Status</td>
        <td><select name=stats>
                <option value="1">Active</option>
                <option value="0">Inactive</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="btn-update" id="btn-update">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> Save Updates
            </button>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

everything is working it's just an additional functionality in the edit form page

Comment: Can also add a column in your database user table which is like `status` then value would be `boolean`. This idea does't delete the actual user but just updates its status. You can then just display your users query only display users with active status.

Comment: i hope you have a loop in edit_form.php

Answer (score 1):

Get the stats like  `$status= $_POST['stats'];` in delete.php
change you `$_GET['edit_id']` to `$_GET['id']`

modify you updated to set the status

```
 $id = $_POST['id']; 
 $status = $_POST['stats']
 $stmt=$db_con->prepare("UPDATE tbluser set status=:status WHERE id=:id");
 $stmt->execute(array(':status'=>$status,':id'=>$id));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call the `delete.php`, you can use ajax.

```
<script>
$.ajax({
    url:'delete.php',
    type:'post',
    data: $('form').serialize()
});
</script>
```

You can get values on the `delete.php`, with the help of `$_POST` or `$_REQUEST`.
And if the `delete.php` code is right, then on `submit` of the `edit_page.php` your datatable can get affected.